# Python recursion is very slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am a novice at python, but was surprised at how slow this recursive call took to execute:

```
def daH(m:int):
    if m == 1:
        return int(1)
    else:
        if m <= .5 * (daH(m-1) * (daH(m-1) +1)):
            return int(daH(m-1))
        else:
            return int(daH(m-1) + 1)

print(daH(10)) # prints 4
print(daH(11)) # prints 5
print(daH(15)) # prints 5    
print(daH(16)) # prints 6

print(daH(106)) # prints ??? (gave up waiting)
```

I ran it on IDLE, python 3.6. I added the INT stuff but it did not help. I had no problems running the standard factorial recursion and printing factorial(106).

Can this attempt at recursion be salvaged?

Comment: Look at how many times you call `daH(m-1)`.

Comment: Just to be clear: this has nothing to do with recursion. The algorithm is slow because of the way it’s written but a recursive solution can be fast.

Comment: btw I believe you can drop that `int` declaration, it's really unnecessary

Comment: Dan Badder recently published blog post about what you should be doing https://dbader.org/blog/python-memoization

Comment: @v Thx 4 heads up! I am following Badder on twitter .  Here is my program now: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2574424/432081

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are computing `daH(m-1)` 3 times, making the algorithm slower than necessary. Instead, calculate it just once and bind the result to a local variable. (Also, not necessary to cast to `int`)

```
def daH(m:int):
    if m == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        r = daH(m-1)
        if m <= .5 * r * (r + 1):
            return r
        else:
            return r + 1
```

Calling the function three times instead of once may not seem like much, but remember that those calls will stack exponentially! You call it three times, and each of those *again* call it three times, and so on. This results in a complexity of O(3<sup>m</sup>), which even for `m=15` results in about 15 *million* recursive calls, as opposed to the 15 that are actually necessary.

Comment: I was casting to INT because I was worried about how I was calculating the binomial coef. nC2. Though integer precision would avoid overflow errors, etc. Plugged in your answer - works like a charm!

Comment: @MikeMathMan If you want to avoid floating point imprecision, you could replace `m <= .5*r*(r+1)` with `2*m <= r*(r+1)` or `m <= (r*(r+1)) // 2` (as `(r*(r+1)` will always be even).

Comment: I change my code using // and got rid of the INT stuff. The line print(type(daHB(1))) outputs "<class 'int'>" - looks good to me!

Answer (score 3):

Since daH is a mathematical function and always produces the same output for a given input, you can cache the values and use them.

**Sample output**

```
$ time python use_cache.py
4
5
5
6
15

real    0m0.194s
user    0m0.144s
sys 0m0.047s
$
```

**Caching decorator**

```
$ cat use_cache.py
def use_cache_when_possible(func):
    cache = {}
    def foo(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = func(*args)
        return cache[args]
    return foo

@use_cache_when_possible
def daH(m):
    if m == 1:
        return int(1)
    else:
        if m <= .5 * (daH(m-1) * (daH(m-1) +1)):
            return int(daH(m-1))
        else:
            return int(daH(m-1) + 1)

print(daH(10))
print(daH(11))
print(daH(15))
print(daH(16))
print(daH(106))
$
```

Comment: Might be overkill for this problem, but very useful in general. Also, you can use `@functools.lru_cache()` instead of creating your own.

Comment: Interesting... not sure how to use in Windows/IDLE, but it is good to know about.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `daH` unnecessary number of times.

Your code make 3 calls to `daH(m-1)` for every call `daH(m)`, which makes exponential complexity, which scales badly, i.e performs badly on larger values of `m`.

You can save the result of call to`daH` and use it in places where you called `daH` with same input, instead of calling the function multiple times.

```
def daH(m:int):
    if m == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        ret_val = daH(m-1)
        if m <= .5 * (ret_val * (ret_val +1)):
            return ret_val
        else:
            return ret_val + 1
```